# Index going out of range in bisect_left in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

I'm writing this piece of code, in which I've used bisect_left function from the bisect module which is a first-party module of Python. I'm using it with two parameters only i.e. sorted_list and target(the one for which I have to find the suitable index value).

The issue is: If my target is greater than the sum of lowest value and highest value, the function is returning the index = len(sorted_li), due to which I'm getting index error. I can use try and except but more than that I'm curious to know why it is behaving like so.

Following is my code:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

li = [10,15,3,6,10]
k  = 19

def binary_search(sorted_list,target):

    index = bisect_left(sorted_list,target)

    print(index)

    if sorted_list[index] == target:
        return index

    else:
        return False

def function(sorted_li,k):

    """
    Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.
    For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.
    """

    print(sorted_li)

    for i in range(len(sorted_li)):

        print('Next iteration')

        print(sorted_li[i])

        target = k - sorted_li[i]

        j = binary_search(sorted_li,target)

        if j:
            if j != i:
                print(sorted_li[i])
                print(sorted_li[j])
                return True
            else:
                if j + 1 < len(sorted_li):
                    if sorted_li[j+1] == target:
                        print(sorted_li[i])
                        print(sorted_li[j+1])
                        return True
                if j - 1 > 0:
                    if sorted_li[j-1] == target:
                        print(sorted_li[i])
                        print(sorted_li[j-1])
                        return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    li.sort()
    a = function(li,k)
    print(a)
```

It's output is as follows:

[image: When k > sum (li's lowest + li's greatest)]

but when I'm changing k to 18, the code is working fine, the output is as follows:

[image: When k <= sum (li's lowest + li's greatest)]

I've tried with various sets of numbers for the same. The output remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `bisect_left` which has next purpose: it looking for the insertion point for x (which is target in your case) in a to maintain sorted order.

So for your case when you call first binary_search first time for `16` (19 - 3), it compare your number with items in `li` list using binary algorithm and then it returns position for insert `5`, because in your list [3, 6, 10, 10, 15] insertion point should be after 15 which is correct.

If you open [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) you can find next method in [searching sorted list](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists)

which does exactly you need, it searching for the exact item in list and return position of it if it exists either it raises `ValueError` because item not found.

```
def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError
```